# Ignoring saved intent when launched from switcher

Tags: android, android-intent, url-scheme

For reference lets say the activity structure of the app is as follows.

I have Activities: A B C

I have a url scheme and an intent filter that launches activity B which will launch C when the server is ready and sends me a message. When C is launched B is finished and destroyed.

The problem I'm having is when I back out of the app with the back button. From C I press back and go back to the web page that launched the app and finish the activity. If I go back to the home screen and launch the app it launches to A as expected, but if I use the app switcher to open the app it launches to C.

How can I get the app switcher to launch A after the app was launched from my intent filter?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually how Android should generally work; if you press the homes button, you're really only *pausing* the app and aren't explicitly saying "go back to the last page within this app" (e.g. the back button).

Now, if you want to implement that behavior, you could simply override the `onPause()` method of `Activity C` and tell it to `finish()` the Activity in the event it is paused (which would fire when the home screen button is pressed). e.g.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    finish();
    super.onPause();
}
```

That, however, isn't really a good idea for 2 reasons:

1. That will kill the `Activity` ANY time `onPause()` is called (e.g. a dialog pops up, there's a phone call, the screen turned off, etc.).
2. Users generally expect apps to behave in a similar way, and changing that structure may result in a poorer user experience.

Now, problem #1 definitely sucks here. It wouldn't be so bad if we could tell WHY the app is pausing, but since we can't, we may want to go with an alternate, albeit hackier, solution...

Let's define "the user leaving the app" as "`onPause()` was called more than 2 minutes ago." Now, when the app is resumed, we'll check the time it was paused against the current time to see if it qualifies as "leaving the app" and then exiting the `Activity` if necessary. e.g.

```
private static final int EXIT_TIME_THRESHOLD = 1000 * 60 * 2; // 2 minutes in milliseconds

private long lastPause = -1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // If it was never paused, setup as normal. If not, let onResume() handle it
    if(lastPause < 1) setup();        
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if(lastPause > 1){
        // If less than 2 minutes has passed since the app was paused, setup normally. Otherwise exit the Activity
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - EXIT_TIME_THRESHOLD < lastPause){
            setup();
            lastPause = -1;    
        }
        else finish();
    }
}

private void setup(){
    */Your normal setup code here */
}

protected void onPause(){
    lastPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Now, that will work in the case that the app is NOT killed by the OS (i.e. it's in the background for a long enough time that Android has decided to kill it to free up memory), but won't in that case because the value of `lastPause` would be reset and it would be treated normally. If you want to get around that, you could store the value inside the app's `SharedPreferences` (just be careful to set the value back to -1 when `Activity A` is opened to prevent issues).